# django-paypal IPN doesn't work

Tags: python, django, paypal, django-paypal

I'm using django-paypal as a payment solution inside my django application. I'm trying to implement a IPN handler.

What happens when I receive an IPN message at my IPN-handling URL the django server crashes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 281, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 321, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 417, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 300, in write
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 286, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(buffer)
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

My payments applications urls.py looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('mysite.payment.views',
    (r'^thank_you/', 'thank_you'),
    (r'^canceled/', 'canceled'),
    (r'^paypal-ipn/', include('paypal.standard.ipn.urls'))
    )
```

To me the error message is pretty useless. Would be great if someone could help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I admit I'm an idiot :)

You don't need ssl for this. But what you need is to do a syncdb before you are able to use it,...

God sometimes it is so easy that you just don't see it.

Comment: >.< ouch! I'm glad it was easy! I had assumed the page was displaying the appropriate messages.

Answer (score 0):

Can you monitor precisely the packet that paypal is sending your server using `tcpdump` or wireshark? It looks like they may be terminating the connection early, but it's hard to tell much without a longer traceback and/or a packet dump.

**Edit:**
I had forgotten about the https messages. Paypal probably requires HTTPS for those callbacks. The dev server won't support that, so unfortunately you will probably need to flesh out your server configuration before you can test that functionality.

Comment: I can use the Instant Payment Notification (IPN) simulator or the sandbox with a "real" request, the Problem is the same. But I'm going to catch the packet with tcpdump now.

Comment: For some reason I only get https messages. So there is not that much to see. But this might be the problem, because I'm running on the django development server, I do not have any ssl support. But I have no idea where to change this paypal behavior.

Comment: That does sound like the difficulty. Https messages won't be very interesting in `tcpdump`, and I believe you have to work with https... paypal won't send those messages in an unencrypted format.

Comment: I tried to use stunnel to provide an ssl enabled server. The problem with that is, that the paypal ipn call goes to port 80 and not 443. I'm confused now. If this is a real https message it should get send to port 443, right?

Comment: Where do the packets you're seeing with `tcpdump` go? Paypal definitely shouldn't be talking SSL to port 80. This seems like something you can probably configure in paypal's system.